# ¿Por que obtengo el error NullPointerException en prueba unitaria con Junit?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, junit, mockito, junit-5

Tengo el siguiente servicio en Java que consulta a una BD a través de dos parémetros (fecha de inicio y final), este servicio manda a llamar al  método **validacionCampos()** de una clase Util y lo que necesito es crear las pruebas unitarias para cubrir la mayor parte del Código desarrollado.

Clase ServiceImpl

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<?> consultarReportes(Integer fechaInicio, Integer fechaFin) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    List<EntityDa> consultarReporte = new ArrayList<EntityDa>();
    try {
        consultarReporte = bitacoraRepository
                .consultarBitacoras(fechaInicio, fechaFin);
        reporteUtil.validacionCampos(consultarReporte);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("An error ocurred looking for Entity Data");
        response.put("success", false);
        response.put("error", e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    response.put("success", true);
    response.put("data", consultarReporte);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Clase Util

```
private static final String DECIMAL = "0.0000";

        public List<EntityDa> validacionCampos(List<EntityDa> lista) {
        for (EntityDa details : lista) {
            if (details.getRango() == null || details.getRango().equals("0")) {
                details.setRango(DECIMAL);
            }
            if (details.getPrima() == null || details.getPrima().equals("0")) {
                details.setPrima(DECIMAL);
            }
        }
        return lista;
        }
```

Tengo la siguiente prueba para cubrir las validacion de los campos null de la clase util, pero me manda un NullPointerException en la linea **claseUtil.validacionCampos(list);**

```
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc
    @SpringBootTest
    public class ClaseTest {
    
    @Autowired
    ClaseUtil claseUtil;
    
    
    @Test
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        EntityDa entity = new EntityDa();
        entity.setRango(null);
        entity.setPrima(null);

        List<EntityDa> list = new ArrayList<EntityDa>();
        list.add(entity);

        claseUtil.validacionCampos(list);

    }
    }
```

alguien sabe por que manda en NullPointer?
o como debe ser el método para probar la clase util?

Comment: Porque claseUtil probablemente sea null. ¿En qué momento la asignas?

Comment: @Mateo y si no la estoy asignando como comentas, como seria?

Comment: Solo se usar Java. De alguna manera tienes que asignar esa variable. Ya sea haciéndola pública, con setters, teniendo una instancia en una variable estática o lo que sea. También puedes optar por verificar que `claseUtil` no sea null antes de seguir. Quizás no sea una solución pero ya no tendrás el error.